# Custom SMTP server - HELO response seen by spam tester is wrong

Tags: email, domain-name-system, smtp

I am setting up a custom .NET-based SMTP server. It is listening on port 25 and responding to HELO command with host name that I configured (it matches the host name resolved by reverse DNS lookup and also I have proper A and MX records in my DNS). The server seems to work well (I can send emails to gmail, yahoo, mail.com, zoho, outlook.com) and the HELO test passes with **www.isnotspam.com**. But **mail-tester.com** and **allaboutspam.com** both see wrong HELO response and warn me about it. That indicates there might be a problem with my server that some other email receiver servers might complain about. Below are some warnings (I replaced my IP and domain name with dummy values).

**Mail-tester.com warning** - notice the exclamation marks

> Your IP address 10.10.10.10 is associated with the domain
>   mail.yourdomain.com. Nevertheless your message appears to be sent from
>   !10.10.10.10!.

**Allaboutspam.com warning**

> Email Server HELO is <[10.10.10.10]>. HELO greeting does not contain a
>   valid domain. We would recommend to have a valid domain in HELO
>   greeting. Ideally HELO greeting should be the same as Email server
>   host name (in FQDN format).

When I connect to my mail server with telnet and issue a HELO I get:

> 250 mail.yourdomain.com

What can be wrong here? Should I care about those warnings?

Comment: Please provide the actual domain names and IP addresses. [Why we ask for this?](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/126632)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be the HELO command issued by my server when **sending** the email to mail-tester.com - i.e. my server's response to mail-tester's HELO didn't really matter. I had misconfigured the object responsible for sending the emails - when using MailKit SmtpClient the key is to set this property http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/P_MailKit_Net_Smtp_SmtpClient_LocalDomain.htm to proper host name (`mail.yourdomain.com` in my case).